# Counting the number of messaging sessions from Twilio

Tags: php, twilio, whatsapp

I'm using Twilio to let community centers and live-events venues to communicate via WhatsApp with their customers.
Each community center/venue (let's just call them "centers") will have an allotted number of WhatsApp messaging sessions. This is based on my understanding that WhatsApp (and thus Twilio) charges per messaging "session" of 24 hours that starts when the business (in this case community center or events-venue) initiates a conversation or replies to a customer initiated conversation.

I want to write a PHP code that finds out for each message that the center sends (whether it's as a reply to a customer's message or an initiation of a conversation) if it still falls within the 24-hour window of the latest session, and if not, it should decrement by 1 the number of remaining WhatsApp messaging sessions of the relevant center.

The centers are stored in a mysql DB and the column is called "remaining_whatsapp_messaging_sessions".

I don't understand if the beginning time of the latest messaging session is accesible through Twilio's API. If it is, I could just see if more than 24 hours have passed since the start of the latest messaging session when the business sends their message.
I tried looking it up in their documentation but I just can't seem to find the answer.

Comment: Good morning. I've asked about this internally at Twilio and will add more when I've heard back.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've heard back regarding WhatsApp, Twilio and sessions:

> There two type of charges:
>
> 1. A Whatsapp fee. This one is taken per conversation. Check out https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/pricing#how-it-works to learn more about conversations.
>    Long story short is yes, it’s 24-hours window. Please note that
>    there is **free-tier**: the first 1000 conversations per account per month
> 2. A Twilio fee. This one is taken per message